# How to load pyrocms Plugin within the theme

Tags: php, pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

I'm creating a plugin, that is return an array. This how my files structure

**myplugin.php**

```
class Plugin_myplugin extends Plugin
{
    function foo()
    {
       return array(1,2,3,4,5);
    }
}
```

In the default.html file, I can access it via `{{ myplugin:foo }}`. Everything is working perfectly,

But I want to get second element of array. Or without using Lex Parser, How can I access via PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it as a parameter to plugin. For example:

```
{{ myplugin:foo pos="position" }}
```

Then in your plugin:

```
class Plugin_myplugin extends Plugin
{
    function foo()
    {
       $pos = $this->attribute('pos');
       $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
       return $arr[$pos];
    }
}
```

That's all.